# SQL Server Express Deployment with C# Application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, setup-deployment

I have written an application in C# using Visual Studio 2010 which uses SQL Server as it's back-end.

I would like to create a setup program for this application with all perquisites such as SQL Server Express and so on.

What I want is setup program to ask the user either to install the SQL Server Express or use the existing instance. If user opts for existing instance then Setup will ask for credentials and write the credentials in configuration file using encryption (Encryption class is already implemented).

If user opts for new instance installation, then setup will install the SQL Server Express with a specific Instance Name and also create the initial database. Setup will then use this instance's credentials in configuration file.

I am new to Setup and Deployment so please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found any solution for this ? Windows installer doesn't give any out of the box features to solve your requirement. To handle this SQL server installation you may need to implement logic and integrate with Windows Installer.

Comment: Still Struggling for the solution!

Comment: Search the forum for ***Windows Installer custom UI***, You will get some idea.